# Add multiple objects under key in NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

What I am trying to achieve is the following, store one value (keyword) under the key (account) in one dictionary and then store that dictionary under another dictionary with the key (list) and finally that dictionary under another dictionary under the key (allKeys).

```
- (void)addFilterForAccount:(NSString *)account forKeyword:(NSString *)keyword inList:(NSString *)list {

    //Set properties for NSStrings
    account = _accountName;
    keyword = _textField2.text;
    list = _listName;
    //Clear the textField
    _textField2.text = @"";
    //Store this information into a dictionary/array
    _keys = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [_keys setObject:keyword forKey:account];

    _keywords = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [_keywords setObject:_keys forKey:list];

    _filters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [_filters setValue:_keywords forKey:@"allKeys"];

    //nomenclature would be:
    //
    //_filters[@"allKeys"][@"//listName\\"][@"//accountName\\"]

    NSLog(@"%@", _filters);
}
```

I have the following code that should do what I want, but the problem at this time is that it doesn't allow for multiple keys. So if I want to store multiple keywords under one list, when I log out it should be like this:

```
2014-09-07 18:31:12.562 Filterfeed[4050:124143] {
    allKeys =     {
        "Breaking News" =         (
                        {
                BreakingNews = romney
                               obama
                               bush
                               clinton;
            }
        );
    };
}
```

But right now it is just one name, and it gets replaced each time I invoke this method.

What actually prints out:

```
2014-09-07 18:31:12.562 Filterfeed[4050:124143] {
    allKeys =     {
        "Breaking News" =         (
                        {
                BreakingNews = romney;
            }
        );
    };
}
```

Comment: You have a fundamental issue in that you are allocated new dictionaries each time, but also your data structure, as shown in your "desired" is a bit confusing.  Your innermost structure has multiple values associated with a single key - so should it be an array?

Comment: Yes I see it should be, but the array would have to contain the keywords under the key account string. Can the array do this? And then store that array into a dictionary under the key list string.

Answer (score 0):

You want this method to be:

```
- (void)addFilterForAccount:(NSString *)account forKeyword:(NSString *)keyword inList:(NSString *)list { 

//Set properties for NSStrings 
account = _accountName; 
keyword = _textField2.text; 
list = _listName; 
//Clear the textField 
_textField2.text = @""; 
//Store this information into a dictionary/array 
_keys = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; 
NSMutableArray *array = [NSUserDefualts standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: list]; 
[array addObject: keyword]; 
[[NSUserDefualts standardUserDefaults] setObject: array forKey: list]; 
[[NSUserDefualts standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; 
NSMutableArray *array2 = [NSUserDefualts standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: list]; 
[_keys setObject:array2 forKey:account]; 
_keywords = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; 
[_keywords setObject:_keys forKey:list]; 

_filters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; 
[_filters setValue:_keywords forKey:@"allKeys"]; 

//nomenclature would be: 
// 
//_filters[@"allKeys"][@"//listName\\"][@"//accountName\\"] 

NSLog(@"%@", _filters); 
}
```

Comment: Problem is, that this array will have to be organized by the account. So I would need to add the keyword to the array under the account string key and then add that array as a key under list?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I meant to say you set the array as the object for the key.

Comment: You want the array to be your list of keywords.

Comment: Right but the array should store the keywords under the account string.

Comment: Yes, the account key.

Comment: But if I change the accountName list to a different account, the keyword will be added to the same array and all the keywords would be combined together?

Comment: Just have a holdingArray for each dictionary then.

Comment: This code is executed in sort of a detail view of a cell. So one accountName string would have an array of keywords and another would have a speerage section in that array.

Comment: If you have a finite amount of dictionaries then create that amount of arrays.

Comment: Can we iMessage or something I would like to explain better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60800/discussion-between-wyatt-mufson-and-isa-ranjha).